# vb.net count distinct row in sql and store it in INT variable

Tags: vb.net

i need to count the distinct row in sql database
and after that the result will be stored in Int variable

for example
count the distinct row(SalesID) in tblSales(table)
and store it in NUM(int variable) .

TIA :)

```
    Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
        Try
           Dim cn As New SqlConnection(con)
           Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(query, cn)
           Dim cb As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
           Dim dt As New DataTable
           da.Fill(dt)

           Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
           Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub btnFinish_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFinish.Click 
       dim count as string = "select distinct count(SalesID) from tblSales"  
       ExecuteQuery(count) 
       dim Num as Integer = Int32.Parse(Val(count)) 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please provide what you have tried.

Comment: i tried this one

Private Sub btnFinish_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFinish.Click

dim count as string = "select distinct count(SalesID) from tblSales"
ExecuteQuery(count)
dim Num as Integer = Int32.Parse(Val(count))
End Sub

Comment: Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
        Try
            Dim cn As New SqlConnection(con)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(query, cn)
            Dim cb As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)

            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function

Comment: edit your question and add what you've tried there.

Answer (score 3):

you could try something like this

```
Dim num As Integer
Dim sql As String
sql = "select count(distinct SalesID) from tblSales"
Using con As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Using com As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        con.Open()
        num = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar())
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: @PaoloHerreraBabas. Its Correct then tick it. Because it use for future reference